# Is it possible to: Java DTO --> Swagger --> Java DTO?

Tags: java, swagger, dto

In a very big Java app with lot's of DTOs, I want to export to an external project only the DTOs that are relevant to REST calls, and even better to export a part of them (the minimum required for REST calls).

The project uses Swagger and I am wondering if it is possible to take the output of Swagger (uses Java DTOs to create JSON\YAML files), which have the **exact** content I need, as an input to generate new Java DTO files. The generated files will be only those needed for REST and I will be able to easily export them.

Is this possible?
If not, what is the best approach to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't go by swagger. You may export a DTO from you current project into YAML, then when you regenerate the code may not be exactly the same (members may not be final, if there was a custom toString you'd lose it etc.). If your old project is dead, simply copy/paste the files into the new project. If the DTO is really common between the two projects, then create a data module containing only the DTO and make both projects depend on it (that is the cleanest way to go IMO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check out [swagger.generator.io](https://generator.swagger.io/) where you can generate a whole client library (including DTO classes) for your specified swagger definition file. For documentation please refer to their [github page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators). You can also do the generation of the API client locally utizing the [swagger codegen tools](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/).